# Creating a JS browser-plugin utility like SWFObject

Tags: javascript, swfobject, browser-plugin

I am thinking that SWFObject would be a great example to learn from for my own browser plugin, but looking at swfobject.js it's all compressed to the point of unreadability and also is quite large.

Has anyone already created a generic plugin toolkit that is similar, or are there good resources which dissect how it works in more of a tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SWFObject team provides an uncompressed copy of SWFObject in every download... it's in the `src` folder. It's isn't packed with comments, but it's quite legible.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was just looking at the version I was deploying.